# Setting up multiple environmental variables

Tags: windows-7, java, environment-variables, .net

I already have a variable named PATH set for my .net 4 framework. I want to set up a variable for JAVA but when i use a variable-name other than PATH it doesn't get Java working and if i change default .net variable name PATH to something else .net framework gives problem.
Whats' the solution?

Regards,
Sanket

Comment: I don't understand why you need to set another variable for path when you can provide path for java in the same variable.

Comment: You could always set the variables inside a launch script. I'm confused why you need different `PATH` values for running .NET and Java though. Your `PATH` usually tells the OS where to look for executables to run. If that's really what you're changing, then you should just take the union of the two. On Windows you just separate each path in the `PATH` with a semicolon.

Comment: you should append rather than replacing the values to the PATH. That way all executables will be available to PATH .

Comment: @Sanket Path - I re-posted my comment as an answer below so that you can accept it. :)

Answer (score 4):

(From comment above)

You could always set the variables inside a launch script. I'm confused why you need different PATH values for running .NET and Java though. Your PATH usually tells the OS where to look for executables to run. If that's really what you're changing, then you should just take the union of the two. On Windows you just separate each path in the PATH with a semicolon.